# Testing Time input field with prefix

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, spectron

I have a Form with Time input field

```
<ui-time-input _ngcontent-c21="" class="ml-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="time" hidepostfix="true" label="" _nghost-c30="" id="p-at-tt-time-input" ng-reflect-id="p-at-tt-time-input" ng-reflect-label="" ng-reflect-hide-postfix="true" ng-reflect-hide-validation-message="true" ng-reflect-name="time">
<div _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field no-label-placeholder mat-form-field-empty hide-postfix">
    <div _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field-flex">
        <div _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field-infix ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
            <input _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-input-element ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="time" type="time" ng-reflect-name="time" data-prefix="at">
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field-underline"></div>
    </div><span _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper"><label _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-form-field-label"></label></span>
    <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
</div>
</ui-time-input>
```

[image]

The Input Field looks like:

I would like to test the form. I use

`await this.app.client.setValue(`//*[@id="p-at-tt-time-input"]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hAqd.png)/input`, '12:30');`

But i get 
`invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.` error

Comment: wait, why do you not write `element(by.xpath("...xpath..."))`. is this protractor syntax?

Comment: no this is spectron syntax. I must use spectron since the app is electron app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might first need to perform a `click` on that element and then perform a `setValue` or `keys`

```
await this.app.client.click(//*[@id="p-at-tt-time-input"]/div/div/div1/input);
await this.app.client.setValue(//*[@id="p-at-tt-time-input"]/div/div/div1/input, '12:30');

OR

await this.app.client.click(//*[@id="p-at-tt-time-input"]/div/div/div1/input);
await this.app.client.keys(//*[@id="p-at-tt-time-input"]/div/div/div1/input, '12:30');
```